# Unnumbered theorem-like environments using thmtools

Tags: numbering, theorems, thmtools

This produces an error (`\* already defined`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no]{theorem}
\begin{document}
     Nothing.
\end{document}
```

Adding package `amsthm` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no]{theorem}
\begin{document}
     Nothing.
\end{document}
```

But what should I do if I would like to define my own `proof` environment (without changing my existing LaTeX code)?  This produces an error (`\proof already defined`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no]{proof}
\begin{document}
     Nothing.
\end{document}
```

I could use package `ntheorem` as the backend of package `thmtools`, but the documentation of `thmtools` says that some features do not work with `ntheorem`.

Comment: Just don't define `proof`: the environment provided by `amsthm` has many good features.

Comment: I would like to change the appearance of the displayed proof.

Comment: Why don't you tell what changes you want to make?

Comment: Do not know yet.  I would like to play with the features of `thmtools` until I am satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply fool LaTeX in thinking that `proof` is not defined:

```
\let\proof\relax
\declaretheorem[numbered=no]{proof}
```